# Will encryption of an apk file prevent hackers from decompiling it?

Tags: android, security, encryption, apk, decompiling

Is it possible to secure an apk file by encrypting it to prevent decompilation. I just want to prevent the hackers from editing the source code of apk and re-uploading it to www.attacker-websites.com.

Suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: Not possible.Enable the proguard it will help to obfuscates your code.refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you encrypt an APK, the system must have a key to decrypt it so that it can run. However, the attacker could root the device to obtain the key and then decrypt it. After the app is decrypted, Java is not difficult to reverse engineer. Unfortunately, there is no fool-proof way of preventing the reverse engineering of Android apps. The best option is currently to make the attacker's life miserable by using obfuscation (even though this goes against Kerckhoffs's principle). Tools such as ProGuard help to make your application more difficult to reverse engineer (but again, not impossible).

In short, unfortunately encrypting the APK will not be advantageous when the attackers likely have root access to their device and can find the key.

Comment: I don't understand how can decryption of an apk is possible if you become root. The key to decrypt the message is provided by the developer right?

Comment: The Android application cannot run while it is encrypted. It will need to be decrypted before it is run, and for that it needs a key. The key needs to be located somewhere that is inaccessible to the user, but accessible to the system so that it can decrypt the apk before running the application. But if the user has root access, it doesn't matter where the file is located; the user can access it when it is found.

Answer (score 0):

well there is not standard way to prevent hackers as its there job to find a way around. Many people use dex2jar to get the source code by De-compiling apk file. but usually any code inside a thread like Async task is not De-compiled, you can't stop hackers from stealing code but you can make there job hard by using threads.